# How to get WordPress to save upload file beyond web root

Tags: security, directory, uploads, paths

I am using nginx on a multisite install.

I am trying to get WordPress to save uploads to a folder beyond the webroot :

```
/home/mydomain/file_secure
```

as opposed to

```
/home/mydomain/public_html/wp-content/uploads
```

I have successfully moved the uploads directory around inside the webroot with the following filter:

```
add_filter('upload_dir', 'my_upload_dir');
$upload = wp_upload_dir();
//remove_filter('upload_dir', 'my_upload_dir');

function my_upload_dir($upload) {
    global $blog_id;
    $upload['basedir'] = '/home/mydomain/file_secure/'.$blog_id;
    $upload['subdir'] = '';
    $upload['path'] = $upload['basedir'] . $upload['subdir'];
    $upload['url']  = $upload['baseurl'] . $upload['subdir'] . '/file_secure.php?file=';


    return $upload;
}
```

This path is writable.  It even creates the directories `file_secure` and `25` ($blog_id)

```
$upload['basedir'] = '/home/mydomain/file_secure/'.$blog_id;
```

I have looked through the core code in WordPress 3.9 `wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php` at the function wp_upload_dir() and noticed that the function description states that

```
* Checks the 'upload_path' option, which should be from the web root folder,
 * and if it isn't empty it will be used.
```

I assumed that when it found my path to be outside the webroot that it should have thrown an error, but I can't find where.

Needless to say, the upload did not make it to the wanted directory.

On a side note, I plan to access the uploaded files from a script in the front end that will serve up the content. `file_secure.php`

Any help / direction here would be much appreciated.  I would really hate to find out that I need to hack the WP core in order to make this possible; but maybe it could become available in a future release.

I would much rather all of the wp-content be located outside of the webroot.

UPDATE: all I seem to be able to do when changing the upload path from the `upload_dir` filter is create the folder where I want the file to go; but it does not actually save the file there.  It reverts back to the default settings.

ANOTHER UPDATE: WordPress seems to think that the file exists because it creates an attachment post, but there is no file in the intended directory and the URL on the attachment simply has the default URL structure and not the one that I set above.

So now I am trying to investigate what is going on during the attachment post creation.  If anyone can spot what I may be doing wrong, please let me know.

Comment: Are you trying to move ALL uploads or certain uploads directory? There's a constraint you can define in wp-config that apprently sets the uploads folder: [View Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_uploads_folder)

Comment: all uploads would be fine, but the `'upload_dir'` filter should replace the uploads folder set in the `wp-config` file

Comment: Your server/OS may prevent uploads outside of the web root.  There are server and filesystem level configuration issues to worry about when you do this.

Comment: I checked those specifics and I have write access beyond the webroot with my nginx php script user.  As noted above, I can now create the directory with my code, but the actual file does not get saved there.

Comment: It did turn out to be permissions related, but I ended up not using Wordpress to upload the files anyway.